# Reg Ex: Match numbers after specific string

Tags: javascript, regex

Using Reg Ex (in this case Javascript's implementation) is it possible to match the numbers after a particular string?

Example:
In the following example match ***only the numbers*** that follow any string of 'airplane' and not the numbers following any other string.

```
airplane737
train232
motorbike995
car66
airplane747
```

Many thanks in advance for help

D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use this pattern: `/airplane(\d+)/gm`

[Regex101 link](http://regex101.com/r/fR7hT9/1)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The way I understand Reg Ex is your answer will match the string 'airplane737' and not 737 (or also 747 if gm)

Comment: It puts 737 into the capture group. You can see it on Regex101. There's also a Code Generator for Javascript. Love that website.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal regex element to use here would be a look-behind assertion on airplane. For example, in Perl this could be done with `/(?<=airplane)\d+/`. That would match one or more digits only after airplane, without including airplane in the match content.

Unfortunately, JavaScript does not support look-behind assertions (although, strangely, it does support look-ahead assertions; see http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html). Thus there's no way to accomplish what you want in JavaScript. You can use Zoff Dino's solution to match everything (airplane and digits) and use a capture group to extract the digits; that's the best option.